# How to perform a group join in .NET Core 3.0 Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

With the changes to .NET Core 3.0 I am getting

> ... NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate
>   either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
>   information.)  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of
>   the LINQ expression 'GroupJoin, ...

This is a really simple query so there must be a way to perform it in .NET CORE 3.0:

```
 var queryResults1 = await patients
            .GroupJoin(
                _context.Studies,
                p => p.Id,
                s => s.Patient.Id,
                (p, studies) => new 
                {
                    p.DateOfBirth,
                    p.Id,
                    p.Name,
                    p.Sex,
                   Studies =studies.Select(s1=>s1)
                }
            )
            .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

I am basically looking for a Linq query (or method syntax as above) which will join Studies onto Patients, and set Studies to an empty list or null if there are no studies for the given patient.

Any ideas?  This was working in .NET Core 2.2.  Also the MSFT link above mentions that the key breaking change is related to client side evaluation and avoiding that the generated query reads entire tables which must then be joined or filtered client side.  However with this simple query, the join should be easily doable server side.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17068), you're attempting a query that isn't supported by the database. EF Core 2 used client-side evaluation to make your code work, but EF Core 3 refuses, because the client-side convenience comes at the cost of hard-to-debug performance problems as the dataset increases.

You can use use `DefaultIfEmpty` to left join the patients' studies and then group manually with `ToLookup`.

```
var query =
    from p in db.Patients
    join s in db.Studies on p.Id equals s.PatientId into studies
    from s in studies.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Patient = p, Study = s };

var grouping = query.ToLookup(e => e.Patient); // Grouping done client side
```

To solve the [N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97197/145173), the above example grabs the full Patient and Study entities, but you can cherry pick columns instead. If the data you need from Patient is too big to repeat for each Study, in the joined query select only the Patient ID, query the rest of the Patient data in a separate non-joined query.

Comment: Answer works!  I guess there is still some work to do in the query translator.  A simple query like this should be translatable.  There should not be performance issues for a simple group join of 2 tables as the dataset increase assuming FK/indexes are correct.  I suspect many people will have tis issue,  a 2 table group join is quite  a standard and often used query.

Comment: @she72 I agree. It looks like the problem stems from the difference in how LINQ and SQL use the "group" keyword. EF Core should translate the LINQ `groupby` into left joins where doing so doesn't pull back more rows than expected. I posted a [comment](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12560#issuecomment-549134668) accordingly.

Comment: I have a follow-up question,  I am still trying to understand why the grouping for this type of query needs to be done client side, seems a limitation of the new LINQ framework.  For the case above I don't see any risks that it slows down client side execution in unexpected ways.  Can you clarify?

Comment: And as a further follow-up the main concern is:  in your reformulated query which groups client side if I have 1000 studies per patient,  I will be loading each patient 1000 times from the DB? is there any alternative to force this work to be done in the DB and return the grouped results?

Comment: @shev72 The only grouping the database understands involve aggregates, for a example a query of patients with a count of studies per patient. The database always returns a rectangular dataset. A hierarchical grouping has to be composed by the client. You could look at it as client-side evaluation or as [part of the ORM](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12560#issuecomment-549134668). In a hierarchical grouping, parent entity data is repeated, though not re-queried.

Comment: Why not do a `.ToList()` rather than the `.ToLookup()`?

Comment: @thalacker `ToList` doesn't group the results. You would just get a flat list of studies (and their related patients) rather than a list of studies grouped by patients.

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same issue and a big struggle with it. It turns out that .net Core 3.0 does not support Join or Groupjoin in method syntax (yet?).
The fun part is though, it does work in Query syntax.

Try this, it's query syntax with a bit of method syntax.
This translates nicely to the correct SQL query with a nice left outer join and it is processed on the database.
I haven't got your models so you need to check the syntax yourselves....

```
var queryResults1 = 
    (from p in _context.patients
    from s in _context.Studies.Where(st => st.PatientId == p.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        p.DateOfBirth,
        p.Id,
        p.Name,
        p.Sex,
        Studies = studies.Select(s1 => s1)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: By the way, the Join and GroupJoin with Method syntac DO work with the non-core Framework and EF. And do translate to the right query that is pocessed server side

Comment: what is studies in studies.Select(s1 => s1)

Comment: The models were not included in the question so I do not know the studies model.
My best guess is that this is a virtual collection in the model.

Comment: **All** query syntax is translated to fluent / lambda / "method" syntax so if it translates in query syntax, the _equivalent_ fluent query will also translate.

Comment: .net 6 here and it is still not working with lambda syntax