# How to perform a group join in .NET Core 3.0 on a large database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I need to group join 2 tables say Patients and Studies and group by Patients, however my database is very large 100,000+ patients and multiple studies per patient.

This question is very closely related (but old ) question  [How to perform a group join in .NET Core 3.0 Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622571/how-to-perform-a-group-join-in-net-core-3-0-entity-framework).

The answer to that question proposes  the following query,

```
var query =
    from p in db.Patients
    join s in db.Studies on p.Id equals s.PatientId into studies
    from s in studies.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Patient = p, Study = s };

var grouping = query.ToLookup(e => e.Patient); // Grouping done client side
```

which overcomes the exception

> ... NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate
> either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
> information.) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the
> LINQ expression 'GroupJoin, ...:

The issue I have with the solution is that ToLookup is evaluated client side and requires loading of the whole dataset.  Is there some way to perform the grouping server side, then applying paging and then obtain the lookup in order to limit amount of data retrieved by the client.

Comment: Why in this case you do not use `Include`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query =
    from p in db.Patients
    select new 
    { 
        Patient = p,
        Studies = db.Studies.Where(s => s.PatientId == p.Id).ToList()
    };
```