# How to convert SQL with LEFT JOIN to EF CORE 3 LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to convert this SQL:

```
SELECT
  sb.Id AS id,
  sb.name as name,
  sb.age AS age,
  sb.BirthDay as BirthDay,
  su.UnitId AS unitId,
  sb.WorkedInDodo AS workedInDodo,
  sb.RelativesWorkedInDodo AS relativesWorkedInDodo,
  sb.PhoneNumber AS phoneNumber,
  sb.Email AS email,
  sb.DeliveryCheck AS deliveryCheck,
  sb.RestaurantCheck AS restaurantCheck,
  sb.StandardsRatingCheck as standardsRatingCheck,
  sb.SocialNetwork AS socialNetwork,
  sb.SocialNetworkId AS socialNetworkId,
  sb.socialNetworkScreenName AS socialNetworkScreenName,
  sb.SourceOfInformationAboutSecretBuyers AS SourceOfInformationAboutSecretBuyers,
  sb.suitable AS suitable,
  sb.SocialNetworkMessagingEnable as socialNetworkMessagingEnable,
  sb.IsInGroup as isInGroup,
  sb.IsKeyWord as IsKeyWord,
  sb.IsBanned as IsBanned,
  sb.IsFraud as IsFraud,
  sb.LastUnitsUpdateUtcDate as lastUnitsUpdateUtcDate,
  sb.Comments as comments,
  sb.MessagingApproval as messagingApproval,
  sb.ProcessDataApproval as processDataApproval,
  sb.CreatedDateTimeUtc AS createdDateTimeUtc,
  sb.ModifiedDateTineUTC AS modifiedDateTime,
  sb.Country AS country,
  sb.PhoneNumberEditedUtc AS PhoneNumberEditedUtc
  FROM (select * from
    (SELECT  s.*,
    IF(s.LastSearchMessageDateUtc is null, 0, 1) as searched,
    IF(cc.Id is null, 0, 1) as onCheck
    FROM secretbuyers s
    JOIN secretbuyerunits sbu ON sbu.SecretBuyerId = s.Id
    LEFT JOIN outgoingMessageQueue mq ON mq.Type = 1 AND mq.VkUserId = s.SocialNetworkId and mq.State in (1,2)
    LEFT JOIN checkcandidates cc ON cc.SecretBuyerId = s.id AND cc.State IN (1,4) AND cc.Date >= @p_checkBeginDateTime AND cc.Date <= @p_checkEndDateTime
    WHERE sbu.UnitId = @p_unitId
    AND (s.LastSearchMessageDateUtc is null OR s.LastSearchMessageDateUtc < @p_lastSearchMessageDateUtcLimit)
    AND ((@p_deliveryCheck = true AND s.DeliveryCheck = true) OR (@p_restaurantCheck = true AND s.RestaurantCheck = true) OR (@p_standardsRatingCheck = true AND s.StandardsRatingCheck = true))
    AND s.Suitable = true
    AND s.IsRemove = false
    AND mq.Id is null
    AND s.IsBanned = false
    AND s.IsFraud = false
    AND s.IsAutoSearchable = true
    group by s.Id
    Order By onCheck ASC, searched asc, s.LastSearchMessageDateUtc asc) as temp
    LIMIT @p_count) AS sb
  JOIN secretbuyerunits su ON su.SecretBuyerId = sb.Id;
```

to EF Core 3.0 linq. The main problem is left joins. At first I've tried to do it like this:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<MysteryShopper>> FindMysteryShoppers(
        SearchMysteryShoppersParameters searchParameters, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var lastSearchEdge = _nowProvider.UtcNow().Date.AddDays(-3);

        bool shouldHaveDeliveryCheckMark = ShouldHaveDeliveryCheckMark(searchParameters.SearchType);
        bool shouldHaveRestaurantCheckMark = ShouldHaveRestaurantCheckMark(searchParameters.SearchType);
        bool shouldHaveStandardsCheckMark = ShouldHaveStandardsCheckMark(searchParameters.SearchType);

        var lastCheckupEdgeDate = searchParameters.CheckupDates.Max().AddDays(-30);

        return await _ratingsContext.SecretBuyers.AsNoTracking().Where(ms => !ms.IsBanned &&
                !ms.IsFraud
                && ms.IsAutoSearchable
                && ms.Suitable
                && !ms.IsRemove
                && ms.SocialNetworkMessagingEnable
                && (ms.LastSearchMessageDateUtc == null
                    || ms.LastSearchMessageDateUtc < lastSearchEdge)
            )
            .Where(ms => !shouldHaveDeliveryCheckMark && ms.DeliveryCheck)
            .Where(ms => !shouldHaveRestaurantCheckMark && ms.RestaurantCheck)
            .Where(ms => !shouldHaveStandardsCheckMark && ms.StandardsRatingCheck)
            .Where(ms => ms.MysteryShopperUnits
                .Any(u => searchParameters.UnitIds.Contains(u.UnitId))
            )
            .GroupJoin(_ratingsContext.Checkups.AsNoTracking().Where(cc => !_cancelledStates.Contains(cc.State)), ms => ms.Id,
                cc => cc.SecretBuyerId, (ms, cc) => new
                {
                    MysteryShopper = ms,
                    LastCheckupDate = cc
                        .Max(c => c.Date)
                }
            )
            .GroupJoin(_ratingsContext.Messages.AsNoTracking().Where(m =>
                    m.Type == OutgoingMessageType.CandidateSearch
                    && (m.State == OutgoingMessageState.Sending || m.State == OutgoingMessageState.Waiting)),
                ms => ms.MysteryShopper.SocialNetworkId,
                m => m.VkUserId,
                (ms, m) =>
                    new {ms.MysteryShopper, ms.LastCheckupDate, HasPendingMessages = m.Any()})
            .Where(ms => !ms.HasPendingMessages)
            .Where(ms => ms.LastCheckupDate < lastCheckupEdgeDate)
            .OrderBy(ms => ms.LastCheckupDate != null)
            .ThenBy(ms => ms.MysteryShopper.LastSearchMessageDateUtc != null)
            .ThenBy(ms => ms.MysteryShopper.LastSearchMessageDateUtc)
            .Select(ms => ms.MysteryShopper)
            .ToArrayAsync(ct);
    }
```

After running this query I got error:

> ...  by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

After that I discovered from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092869/ef-core-2-2-linq-query-not-working-in-ef-core-3-0) that you can't make group by queries evaluated on client anymore.

After more searching I've discovered another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622571/how-to-perform-a-group-join-in-net-core-3-0-entity-framework). So i've re-written my method like this:

```
        private async Task<IEnumerable<MysteryShopper>> FindMysteryShoppers(
        SearchMysteryShoppersParameters searchParameters, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var lastSearchEdge = _nowProvider.UtcNow().Date.AddDays(-3);

        bool shouldHaveDeliveryCheckMark = ShouldHaveDeliveryCheckMark(searchParameters.SearchType);
        bool shouldHaveRestaurantCheckMark = ShouldHaveRestaurantCheckMark(searchParameters.SearchType);
        bool shouldHaveStandardsCheckMark = ShouldHaveStandardsCheckMark(searchParameters.SearchType);

        var lastCheckupEdgeDate = searchParameters.CheckupDates.Max().AddDays(-30);

        var mysteryShoppersLeftJoinedWithCheckups = from ms in _ratingsContext.Set<MysteryShopper>()
            where ms.MysteryShopperUnits
                .Any(u => searchParameters.UnitIds.Contains(u.UnitId)
                          && !shouldHaveStandardsCheckMark && ms.StandardsRatingCheck
                          && !shouldHaveRestaurantCheckMark && ms.RestaurantCheck
                          && !shouldHaveDeliveryCheckMark && ms.DeliveryCheck
                          && !ms.IsBanned
                          && !ms.IsFraud
                          && ms.IsAutoSearchable
                          && ms.Suitable
                          && !ms.IsRemove
                          && ms.SocialNetworkMessagingEnable
                          && (ms.LastSearchMessageDateUtc == null || ms.LastSearchMessageDateUtc < lastSearchEdge))
            join cc in _ratingsContext.Set<Checkup>()
                on ms.Id equals cc.SecretBuyerId into checkups
            from cc in checkups.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where !_cancelledStates.Contains(cc.State)
            select new {MysteryShopper = ms, LastCheckupDate = checkups.Max(c => c.Date)};


        var mysteryShoppersLeftJoinedWithCheckupsAndMessages =
            from mysteryShopperWithCheckup in mysteryShoppersLeftJoinedWithCheckups
            join m in _ratingsContext.Set<Message>()
                on mysteryShopperWithCheckup.MysteryShopper.SocialNetworkId equals m.VkUserId into messages
            from m in messages.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where m.Type == OutgoingMessageType.CandidateSearch && (m.State == OutgoingMessageState.Sending ||
                                                                    m.State == OutgoingMessageState.Waiting)
            select new
            {
                mysteryShopperWithCheckup.MysteryShopper,
                mysteryShopperWithCheckup.LastCheckupDate,
                HasPendingMessages = messages.Any()
            };

        var orderedMysteryShoppersWithoutPendingMessage =
                from mysteryShopperWithCheckupAndMessage in mysteryShoppersLeftJoinedWithCheckupsAndMessages
                where !mysteryShopperWithCheckupAndMessage.HasPendingMessages &&
                      mysteryShopperWithCheckupAndMessage.LastCheckupDate < lastCheckupEdgeDate
                orderby mysteryShopperWithCheckupAndMessage.LastCheckupDate != null,
                    mysteryShopperWithCheckupAndMessage.MysteryShopper.LastSearchMessageDateUtc != null,
                    mysteryShopperWithCheckupAndMessage.MysteryShopper.LastSearchMessageDateUtc
                select mysteryShopperWithCheckupAndMessage.MysteryShopper;

        return await orderedMysteryShoppersWithoutPendingMessage.ToArrayAsync(ct);
    }
```

But now i get another error:

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

After some more testing i know for sure that checkups.Max(c => c.Date)} and HasPendingMessages = messages.Any() is the source of this error. How to fix this query? You can suggest completely different solution or approach. The main idea is to bring logic from sql to c#.

PS: Sorry for long question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added navigation properties and nugget Z.EntityFramework.Plus (for IncludeFilter) and rewritten query like this:

```
            var query = _ratingsContext.SecretBuyers
            .AsNoTracking()
            .IncludeFilter(ms => ms.Checkups.Where(cc => !_cancelledStates.Contains(cc.State)))
            .IncludeFilter(ms => ms.Messages.Where(m => m.Type == OutgoingMessageType.CandidateSearch &&
                                                        (m.State == OutgoingMessageState.Sending ||
                                                         m.State == OutgoingMessageState.Waiting)))
            .Where(ms => !ms.IsBanned
                         && !ms.IsFraud
                         && ms.IsAutoSearchable
                         && ms.Suitable
                         && !ms.IsRemove
                         && ms.SocialNetworkMessagingEnable
                         && (ms.LastSearchMessageDateUtc == null || ms.LastSearchMessageDateUtc < lastSearchEdge)
            )
            .Where(ms => !shouldHaveDeliveryCheckMark || ms.DeliveryCheck)
            .Where(ms => !shouldHaveRestaurantCheckMark || ms.RestaurantCheck)
            .Where(ms => !shouldHaveStandardsCheckMark || ms.StandardsRatingCheck)
            .Where(ms => ms.MysteryShopperUnits
                .Any(u => searchParameters.UnitIds.Contains(u.UnitId))
            )
            .Where(ms => !ms.Messages.Any())
            .Select(x => new {MysteryShopper = x, LastCheckupDate = x.Checkups.Max(c => c.Date)})
            .Where(ms => ms.LastCheckupDate < lastCheckupEdgeDate)
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastCheckupDate != null)
            .ThenBy(x => x.MysteryShopper.LastSearchMessageDateUtc != null)
            .ThenBy(x => x.MysteryShopper.LastSearchMessageDateUtc)
            .Select(x => x.MysteryShopper)
            .Take(searchParameters.MessagesPerUnit);
```